# Apache redirect from one subdomain to another

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

Does anyone know a way to do a permanent redirect from a.example.com to b.example.com? I have other subdomains that need to remain as they are though. so:

```
first.example.com -> second.example.com
third.example.com is fine
fourth.example.com is fine
```

I want to do this in the `<VirtualHost>` block rather than an .htaccess to avoid having to redeploy again.

Any thoughts would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add the following `RewriteRule` to your `VirtualHost`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^first.example.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://second.example.com [R=301,L]
```

If you wanted to redirect `first.example.com/some/url` to `second.example.com/some/url`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^first.example.com$
RewriteRule /(.*) http://second.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Recommend you use `[R=302]` whilst testing the rules to avoid problems with 301s getting cached by your browser.